# WinForm button click methods are being renewed. with button onclick_1

Tags: winforms, buttonclick

I just finished completing my winforms app. Suddenly when I was changing background color of gridview. When I started my app for final tests the buttons were not working. I checked their on click code and it was correct. Then I double clicked the button it created new button onClick_1 method. SO now all the buttons are doing it :( I dont' know what to do. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your events are no longer coupled to your code.

Do this for each of your buttons:

- Open your designer
- Click on your button
- Open your properties tab
- In this menu, click on the events button
- You'll find your "Click" event.

Click on the arrow and select the correct event.